# Metasploit Framework console misencodes text

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux

I am running the Metasploit Framework (v4.10.2) on Kali Linux 1.0.7. Some commands return this weird, misencoded (I think) text instead of what it should be returning. What can I do to fix this?

Example:
[image: Text misencoding example]

Comment: Open a bug ticket on their github?

Comment: Metasploit had a bug where the color codes were not getting displayed properly. The bug was patched in the PR https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/pull/4337. Update the framework to the latest version through msfupdate and then check. If you still get an error, please open a new issue at https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/issues

Comment: I made a bug ticket (https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/issues/4772)

Comment: Updating MSF sadly didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Well I think that MSF helped @techgod52 through his problem but he did not update this question. Check the bug ticket for more.